# If a condition satisfied or an error happened

Tags: c++, c++11, exception

I have the following case:

```
try{
    auto result = do_something(some_input); //do_something() may throw exceptions 
    if (result == bad){
        do_something_else(some_input);
    }
}
catch(...){
     do_something_else(some_input);
}
```

**Some explanation:**

1. `do_something()` returns `bad` if the process succeeded but the accuracy of process was not that good (It Computer-Vision process).
2. `do_something()` throw exception if it could not process the data due to some missing information or very bad input.
3. In both 1 & 2, I want the flow to go to another method which is `do_something_else()`.

**My questions:**

1. Is this design bad? I feel like I using exceptions wrong.
2. Is it possible to merge them in some way like:

Theoretical code:

```
auto result = do_something(some_input); //do_something() may throw exceptions 
if (result == bad OR exception was thrown){
    do_something_else(some_input);
}
```

Comment: You could throw if `result == bad`, would that help?

Comment: @JanGroothuijse I see.. this could help. thanks

Comment: @HumamHelfawi @ what kind of a place in the code you are having this? I mean is some other class is calling this code (function) explicitly?

Comment: @SupunWijerathne let us say in the main for simplicity

Comment: @HumamHelfawi what kind of things(what they do) you are having inside doSome() and doSomeOther() ? I think more than exception handling, you are having a problem with your design. :))

Comment: @SupunWijerathne do_something applies some algorithm.. if it fails, another algorithm(do_something_else) should be called

Answer (score 2):

I suggest something like this

```
bool suceeded = false;

try 
{ 
   auto result = do_something
   if (result != bad)
   {
        succeeded = true;
   }

}
catch (specific_exceptions)
{
   // Log or do something useful here
}

if (!succeeded)
{
  do_something_else
}
else 
{
    use result
}
```

This attempts to keep the natural flow of your application out of exceptional cases, and to handle the two failures in their own distinct fashion while still funneling them to a single continuing case.

Answer (score 1):

You may wrap the method:

```
auto try_do_something(SomeInputType& someinput) noexcept
{
    try {
        return do_something(some_input); //do_something() may throw exceptions 
    } catch (...) {
        // extra logging ?
        return bad;
    }
}
```

and then

```
if (try_do_something(some_input) == bad) {
    do_something_else(some_input);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd go with something like:

```
try {
    auto result = do_something(some_input);
    if (result == bad) throw BadResultException();
} catch (...) {
    do_something_else(some_input);
}
```

Naturally, this requires you to define your own exception types, but that's reasonably trivial.

To strictly answer your question, though, no, what you're asking isn't really possible as it stands because of how exceptions work. You need to do something like this (or your proposed solution) instead.

Comment: Base the normal flow of execution on an exception is somehow perverse.